# Getting form's name within Angular (this.form.name)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-form

There is a simple form

```
<ng-form name="foo">
    <button />
</ng-form>
```

Click on the button should alert the form name ***foo***.

Is there an angular-way to do that?

**EDIT:** Tell me my parent's name is a possible solution.

Comment: where do you want to get a `form` name?

Comment: @PankajParkar: within the form

Comment: @Vienna I have written an answer below. Please have a look. It will work. Thanks!

Comment: @krishnaxv thank you, I've seen it, but it is not the answer of my question.

Comment: Why not just this? If you get the form name just put it in a hidden field and then access it normally: `<ng-form name="foo">`
   `<input type="hidden" value="MY_FORM_NAME">`
    `<button ng-click="alert(MY_FORM_NAME)"></button>`
`</ng-form>`

Comment: the only way to do this would be to use `angular.element(someButton).parent.name`, but this assumes that you have a reference to the `someButton`, and that the button's parent is indeed the form element.

Comment: `my.parent.name` would also help Instead of `someButton.parent.name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the button has the form as it's direct parent, you can utilize the `$event` property on `ng-click` to traverse the DOM and locate the parent form element.  This uses `angular.element(someElement).parent()`.

```js
$scope.showFormName = function($event) {
  $scope.formName = angular.element($event.target).parent()[0].name;
};
```

```html
<button ng-click="showFormName($event)">Show Form Name</button>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/yDPc76rqUHpOcL2aGeIU?p=preview

If the button is not a direct descendant of the form element, or is not within the form itself, then more advanced DOM traversal may be required, most likely through JQuery, since this isn't part of the design goals of the Angular framework.

Comment: I'm glad this will work for you, and I'm sorry that it took so long for us to come to an understanding of the problem, as well.  I'll clean up some of those old comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access it on `$scope`:

`$scope.foo`

Answer (score 0):

`ng-click` expects either an [`Angular` expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) or a function in the current scope. It looks like `Angular` does not allow you to use global scope methods.

> Angular uses `$parse` service to evaluate the expression in
>   `ng-click="expression"`.

`$parse` uses string parsing to interpret the `expression` and it restricts your access to variables, functions, and objects to just those which are properties of the `$scope` object, or properties of any `$parent` scope objects.

Just try this in your `Template` & `Controller`!

> **Template**
>
> ```
> ng-click="alert(foo.$name)"  <!-- foo ~ MY_FORM_NAME in your case -->
> ```
>
> **Controller**
>
> ```
> $scope.alert = function(formName){
>   alert(formName);
> }
> ```

This will execute the `JavaScript` `alert()` properly.

Refer [AngularJS/ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) for more information.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you, but I don't know foo. I want to know foo. It should work like: "I am a button. I am placed in a form and I don't know my form's name. Tell me my form's name".

Comment: `foo` is just the reference to your `form` object, `<ng-form name="foo">`. Basically, the `name` of your `form` that you have mentioned in your posted code.

Comment: Yes, you are right but imagine, I don't now the forms name, I don't know foo, I have no information about the form. I don't even know, if I am (as button) in a form.